# Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

I'm trying to link VTK library to my project on Windows 7. The error I get is:

`Error  C1083   Cannot open include file: 'vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h': No such file or directory`

The thing in my code that provokes the error is `#include<QVTKWidget2.h>`.

Src and build directories of my VTK copy are separate. The linking tool I use is `cmake`. The build tool: `VS 2015`.

My `CMakeLists.txt` and VTK's cache u can see below.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(PROJECT Pro)
project(${PROJECT})

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS false)
message("  BUILD_SHARED_LIBS " ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS})
list(APPEND CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -static)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

set(VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS
    "D:/libs/VTK-7.1.1"
    )

set(VTK_QT_INCLUDE_DIR
    "D:/libs/VTK-7.1.1/GUISupport/QtOpenGL"
    )

include_directories(${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VTK_QT_INCLUDE_DIR})

# ... Local src declaration

add_executable(${PROJECT} ${PRO_APP_HEADERS}${PRO_APP_SOURCES})

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  message("VTK_LIBRARIES is set.")
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  message("! VTK_LIBRARIES are not set completely")
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif(VTK_LIBRARIES)
```

**VTK's cache**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hot8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on "Advanced" in the VTK's CMake (on the top, next to the search bar), you will see many more options. One of them is Module_vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL, make sure it is checked.

In your CMake, I don't think your include_directories clause does anything. The paths you are linking to are not to the library, but rather to the sources of the library, the actual path to the library would be `D:\VTK_build_directory\include\vtk-7.1.1\`, where VTK_build_directory is wherever you build VTK (I recommend using `INSTALL` to build VTK, then the result will be in the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX directory, which you can specify in VTK's CMake). However, in any case it is not needed anyway since you are already using the `include(${VTK_USE_FILE})`, which will setup all include files. So, unless there is some other use not apparent from your example, you can delete the whole

```
set(VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS
    "D:/libs/VTK-7.1.1"
)

set(VTK_QT_INCLUDE_DIR
    "D:/libs/VTK-7.1.1/GUISupport/QtOpenGL"
)

include_directories(${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${VTK_QT_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: I checked this flag and 'vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h' is visible now. Thank u so much! Though since we started talking about libs installation... There’s no general ‘include’ directory in the build… Please, could u look through my comment to the 1st answer (by Joel)? It’s right about building and installation. I'm confused about the libs usage difference on Windows and Linux. Is it correct not to install them on Win?

Comment: I don't know if it's "correct", but it is by far the easiest way, hence my recommendation to use INSTALL: in CMake you just specify your desired install directory (default on windows will likely be C:/Program Files/VTK) and then once it's configured and generated, you just build the INSTALL project (I see you said you are using VS 2015, so just open it in VS and on the very top you have `CMakePredefinedTargets -> INSTALL`, just right click -> build and it will generate the library structured in a way that the `include(${VTK_USE_FILE})` in your project's CMake will set all the paths correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that file "vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h" is actually located in one of those included dirs (${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}  or  ${VTK_QT_INCLUDE_DIR})  (you did not mention whether it is there), and that you have permissions to it.

Comment: That's it. "vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h" presents neither in the src dir, nor in the build one. On my Linux I can find this file in a particular 'include' subfolder of /usr, but VTK had been installed after having been built there (VTK 7.0.0). I do not INSTALL VTK on Windows. I just operate with directories where the src and build lie. However, isn’t it weird that initial src package misses a file used by it’s own?.. Exact version I unpacked on Windows is 7.1.1 (zip package). For tar.gz the same. It's really curious that initial src package on my Linux doesn't contain this file either...

Comment: Glad to help.  I am not familiar with the "VTK" system.  It may have some options for including the file you need.  The post from @tomj seems to suggest as much.

Comment: This particular file is generated during the CMake process, that's why you don't see it in the source folders. If you open it, you will see it actually does not contain any code, only various macro definitions used to ensure the library is built correctly on the specified platform. You would have to look into the CMake\vtkModule***.cmake files (or documentation) for more details.