# vtkRenderingSceneGraphModule.h missing

Tags: c++, fatal-error, vtk

I am getting the following error when trying to use

```
#include <vtkViewNode.h>
```

in my code. I didn't do anything else besides this. I am getting the following error message:

```
 .../VTK-8.0.1/Rendering/SceneGraph/vtkViewNode.h:29:62: fatal error:vtkRenderingSceneGraphModule.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Everything else i tried so far is working like cylinders or parametric splines. I might be mistaken but if i try searching for "RenderingSceneGraph" on [fossies.org](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/VTK-8.0.1.zip/index_dc.html) there's no match. So to me it seems like it's not part of the VTK 8.0.1 in the first place.

It's needed for several classes according to [their documentation](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/vtkLightNode_8h.html). It's strange though since you can't access any information about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you add the VTK into your project? Do you have the headers in the project's includepath? How did you link to vtk library?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if i'm getting this right. But what i did was add stuff like -lvtkCommon-8.0 and the directories with -L... to a common makefile from the software i'm trying to use vtk in. It worked for stuff like vtkCylinderSource until i got different errors which i haven't fixed yet either. (Stuff like undefined reference to ... within the vtk-Files).

Comment: Post also your makefile or whatever configuration file you're environment is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody had basically the same problem just the other day: [Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285921/errorc1083cannot-open-include-file-vtkguisupportqtopenglmodule-h-no-such-f/47303277)

vtk****Module.h are files generated by CMake when you are configuring the project, that's why you can't find them in a file search of the source code. You have to enable them explicitly, they are among the "advanced" items in the CMake configuration list, then they will be created as you do CMake -> Generate.

It's not clear to me from your comments above whether you are building VTK on your own or if you are using some kind of precompiled package, but in the latter case, I am affraid your package might not be compiled with the vtkRenderingSceneGraph Module and you will have to compile it on your own. Luckily it's not a big problem, you can get some pointers here https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build but in general it's pretty smooth when you use CMake.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I built myself (following the guide you linked) since i need to use it with Qt. What do i exactly have to enable for the SceneGraph-thing? I guess its named "vtkRenderingSceneGraph"? Will look into it later!

Comment: There should be a cmake value named "Module_vtkRenderingSceneGraph" (I can't verify since the scene graph is new for VTK 8.0 and I don't use that yet, but I expect they didn't change this convention). It will be among the "advanced" option, if you're using the CMake GUI you will see it only after checking the "Advanced" checkbox on the top. BTW, since you're using Qt, you will probably also want the Module_vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! I got another VTK related problem now though. I will ask a new question because of formatting. Maybe you can help me again!