# Error C1083 cannot open include file: 'vtkGUISupportQtModule.h' not such file or directory

Tags: c++, vtk

I using Windows 10,1. qt 4.8, vtk 8.2.0, cmake 3.15, tinyxml 2.6.1.. I am trying to compile c++ code but encounter this problem.

I search for this header file in the vtk source code  but no such file exists. I tried searching 'vtkGUISupportQtModule.h' in vtk 6.3, 7.9, 7.1 but none of them has this header file.

Comment: Either your sdk installation is corrupt or you have not installed all the required features/components.

Comment: It's clearly part of 7.0, https://vtk.org/doc/release/7.0/html/vtkGUISupportQtModule_8h.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'vtkGUISupportQtOpenGLModule.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285921/errorc1083cannot-open-include-file-vtkguisupportqtopenglmodule-h-no-such-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are generated by CMake scripts when you are configuring VTK. You have to enable the option "Module_vtkGUISupportQt" in the cmake config of VTK to generate it (it is within the "advanced" options - in the CMakeGUI click the "advanced" checkbox to see it).

However, I'm not sure QT 4.8 will work, at least from the CMake it looks like that VTK 8.2 now supports only QT 5, it does not let me select other options.

Comment: I had a feeling like I already answered this once....and indeed I did! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285921 So I flagged this as duplicate